# Detecting last table data modification?

Tags: mysql, fixtures

During unit tests we have a lot of fixtures being imported all the time and we've come to a point where it is having a serious impact on the total test run time. We've already put our mysql testing db on a ramdisk and instead of re-importing data every time we create a backup of the table and do an INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM.

The next step would be to only reimport data for tables that have been modified instead of all the involved models, but I am looking for a fast way to detect which tables are.

If tried with triggers on the tables (insert, update and delete) that add the name of the table to a variable (because inserting it in a temporary table is slower). The in our fixture manager I just read out the variable, reset those tables and clear the variable value.

However, the triggers slow down everything considerably, apparently mysqls' trigger implementation is not that good, even if its almost doing nothing.

The question is: Is there another very reliable way to detect when a tables data was last modified? Checking the file modification time won't work either as mysql does not purge the cache immediately.

Our tables are in innoDB.